Moments or Mean of transformed Weibull Distribution.
Given the PDF and CDF of the Weibull distribution, denoted as $f_X(x)$ and $F_X(x)$ respectively, the range is $x \geq 0$.
Also, clearly that the mean, $E(x)$ would be $\int^{\infty}_{0}xf_X(x) dx$.
However, if we let $Y=\ln X$, saying the Weibull Distribution is $f_Y$ now, what would be the range of the mean? For example, would it be $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}yf_Y(y) dy$ or $\int^{\infty}_{0}yf_Y(y) dy$ ?
I understand that when $x \rightarrow \infty$ , $y \rightarrow \infty$ . But how about when $x=0$ ?

It is $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

@geetha290krm Oh, but how the $-\infty$ comes from?

$\ln x <0$ for $x<1$ and $\ln x \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0+$.
